# Importing classes in script

Tags: javascript, html, module, export

I have a flask app with the following file located in **static/js/foo.js**:

```
export default class Foo {
  constructor(message) {
    this.message = message;
  }
  toString() {
    return `${this.message}`;
  }
}
```

In my **templates/index.html** file, I'm trying to create an instance of `Foo` as follows:

```
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/foo.js') }}" type="module"></script>
  <script>
    let foo = new Foo('hello foo!');
    console.log(`${foo}`);    
  </script>
```

However, I'm getting the following error in the console: **Uncaught ReferenceError: Foo is not defined**.

Is there a simple way to use a class defined in another file, i.e. `Foo` from within **foo.js**?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your inline script a module as well, and import Foo from foo.js :

```html
<!-- This is not required
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/foo.js') }}" type="module"></script>
-->
<script type="module">
    import Foo from "{{ url_for('static', filename='js/foo.js') }}";
    let foo = new Foo('hello foo!');
    console.log(`${foo}`);
</script>
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules :

> Last but not least, let's make this clear — module features are imported into the scope of a single script — they aren't available in the global scope. Therefore, you will only be able to access imported features in the script they are imported into, and you won't be able to access them from the JavaScript console, for example. You'll still get syntax errors shown in the DevTools, but you'll not be able to use some of the debugging techniques you might have expected to use.